# what is the best way to present data like this?

Tags: info-visualisation, tree

[image: student major syllabus]

note: please disregard the color of the dotted lines. consider it all one color.

This is my best effort to present this data to the user. and i hope there are better ways.

fwiw: what i want to do is show a student his syllabus and color the course nodes using his status in that course; 
status options are:pass fail can-registered can't-register

Also i want to show the pre-requisite and co-requisite connections between all courses

i'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: If the top level parent is a  student and the children are courses and the children of those are course actions, isn't this just a simple tree view?

Comment: it's not, the root node is the major name, the child nodes are courses and the links represent the prerequisites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set each course in a row according to its level
- Order vertically courses according to relations. Try to do not cross relation lines.
- Enable/Disable nodes according to the status of each course

[image]

Comment: great, thank you. does this visualization has a name? so it would be easier to look up jquery tools.